# mysql using tee in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to MySQL (or SQL in general)
I'm trying to get MySQL to write the timestamp into a file with stored procedure using TEE command (I don't think I can use "select into outfile" because I don't want to delete the file, I want to add a line to it...):

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE test_to_file()
    -> begin
    -> TEE /home/ubuntu/test.txt;
    -> SELECT NOW();
    -> end $$
```

However, I get an error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/home/ubuntu/test.txt;
SELECT NOW();
end' at line 3

Thanks for the help

Comment: I've never seen this command used in the context of an actual query and the fact that it's not getting syntax highlighted here strongly suggests it's not part of the MySQL syntax

Comment: From the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html `Tee functionality works only in interactive mode.` likely the reason?

Comment: @Pekka웃, so what you are saying is that there is no way to output a timestamp into a file in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I am not certain that whatever you are trying to do is necessarily a good idea... but there is a simple solution for this.*

Create a table using the [`CSV` Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html).

You can then append to the file by simply inserting into this table.

---

Using `tee` is a client-side feature.  It doesn't write to the server at all, unless you happen to be running the `mysql` *client* on the server machine... in which case, it's only writing to the server machine by coincidence.